# Creating a "portable" .exe (without installer)

Tags: c#, .net, portability

I've recently coded a little program to determine numbers in a picture and it is reliant on two libraries I've used. (DLLs)

Since my target computer is not allowed to install programs due to security reasons, I need to create a portable .exe.
.NET is installed on the target computer but for some reason VS still does not include the libraries I've used in the exe but instead creates an application folder with a setup.exe, some .DEPLOY files and an application manifest.

I am new to VS and .NET in general so this question could be easy to answer, but I'm asking since I've found nothing useful on StackOverflow neither on google.

Comment: Sounds like you are using "deploy" instead of "build". In VS you can usually just take the output of your project directory ("bin/debug" or "bin/release") and copy it to your target machine.

Comment: You can bulit your project and run .exe file without install. The
.exe file you can find in ..\bin\Debug folder

Comment: Both comments above are right except for Win 8, 8.1 and UWP applications. You will not get an exe file out of those, and will have to sideload them on the desired PC.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped. Knowing I can just copy the Release-folder basically is what I needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to do this is to build your application in Release mode (You can pick from Debug or Release in the drop-down). Then go to `C:\Projects\[ProjectName]\[ProjectName]\bin\Release` (The location of your project folder may vary). You'll see a bunch of files but all you really need are the DLLs, executable, and the config if you used one. You won't have to do any setup if you keep the necessary files in the application's folder, just copy them all to a folder on the target computer, create a shortcut if you want then you're good to go.

Comment: Toaster Good answer but I want to confirm one more thing that. If the destination computer does not have dotnet framework (for example .net 4.6.1). How can we include that in the release folder.

Answer (score 9):

You can simply build the application and copy your `bin/Debug` folder along, but that would still mean you need multiple files.

In order to merge all references into the executable, use [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx). Here is [some help calling ILMerge](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9364/Merging-NET-assemblies-using-ILMerge).

Basically, after building, you should do something like this:

```
ilmerge /target:winexe /out:SelfContainedProgram.exe 
    Program.exe ClassLibrary1.dll ClassLibrary2.dll
```

There is just one file you need to send along.

Comment: Sounds like he has troubles location his build directory, not merging all assemblies. That answer would be a helpful next step, but doesn't solve his current problem. Edit: Jup, that's better ;)

Comment: Thanks @ManfredRadlwimmer

Comment: I tried ILMerge before, but there were some Exceptions thrown I couldn't handle. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: @thedood You didn't ask for an easy solution, right ;)

Comment: Not my downvote, but I just wanted to mention that @Grappachu's answer wasn't incorrect and is in fact the recommended approach when [merging WPF apps](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-merge-assemblies-into-wpf-application) (this is even mentioned on the ILMerge page).

Comment: Okay, nice @Groo . Thanks

Comment: @PatrickHofman you're right. I did not. I merged all the DLLs and the .exe together with fody, even though I didn't understand how exactly I managed to do that

Comment: Nice. Good job @thedood

Answer (score 2):

You can just copy all your assemblies into any folder you want. Simply chose "Build" from within Visual Studio and copy the files from `bin/debug` to your destination-folder.

However you have to ensure that all (relative) paths (if existing) still work as you cannot be sure where the user of your program copies the files to.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way could be to use [7zip Packager](https://puvox.software/blog/creating-portable-exe-or-self/), it doesn't need any installer. However, VisualStudio method might be more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue recently.  ILMerge suggestion above is no longer supported.  I found [Fody.Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura/) as a modern replacement.